# CSS positioning and overflow:hidden

Tags: css

I have a **#container** div which wraps all content. And **#slides-wrap** div which is inside **#container**. 
I don't know width of **#sliders-wrap**, but I know size of every **.slide** in it (slides number are unbounded).
Also part of **#slides-wrap** that overflows screen must be hidden.
See attached image as example.

Is it real to do?

[image]

Comment: You need to clarify your question (the last line) as it is utterly vague and no one will be able to answer you as it is currently stated.

Comment: provide a fiddle so we can understand you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you just need to give your #slides-wrap with following properties

```
display: inline
white-space: nowrap;
```

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/sv3a4522/

Comment: Yes, all I need was the white-space: nowrap. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

set z-index for div:

```
#container
{
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:2;
    position: relative;
    width: your-value
}

#container #slides-wrap
{
    width:your-value; /*(1000px or more)*/
    z-index:1;
    position: relative;
}

#slides-wrap .slide
{
    width:100px /*your value*/
}
```

Demo:
[image: demo:]

Comment: It's [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) not `over-flow`, Also `z-index` is not applicable to `static` positioned elements.

Comment: Yes, overflow, add position: relative for div;